# Is there any way to determine if the table row is a child or a parent using the next expression of Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem determining the table row if the table row is a parent of a child. because I want to insert the value of table row separately in the database. I will show you guys the sample the I made today. so here is my example in my console log and I will demonstrate in the image sample where table item or items in a parent or a child.

[image: Items output]

**Pseudocode:**

**1.** Insert the Main item in table database A.

**2.** After the Main item already inserts in the database table A. In the inside of success function of Ajax. set the condition if this Main item has a  Sub Item. if the Main item has a Sub Item get the last insert of the Main item and insert the Sub item in table B of the database. else if the Main item has no Sub Item, The Main item will insert only in table A.

**This is my onClick function for inserting the item in the database.**

```
    $('button#add_to_cart').on('click',function () {

    var customer_id = $('#hidden_customer_id').val();

     var menu = $('#noun_chaining_order').find('tr.condimentParent');

     var condiments= $('#noun_chaining_order').find('tr.editCondiments');

        menu.next('.condimentParent').add(menu).add(condiments).each(function(){


         var $tds_menu = $(this).find("td");

          Qty_menu = $tds_menu.eq(0).text(),
          Item_menu = $tds_menu.eq(1).text(),
          Price_menu = $tds_menu.eq(2).text();



          console.log(Item_menu);



    });


});
```

**Classes**

[image: Classes]

Comment: Seems like they aleady have different clsases. What else do you want?

Comment: I want this Item_menu = $tds_menu.eq(1).text(), differentiate if the table row is a parent or child. in my logs. is that possible?

Comment: because I want to separately insert the parent and the child in the database thats why I want to determine if that is parent or a child.

Comment: Your demonstration image shows an invalid HTML structure **Misplaced non-space characters inside a table.**

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki what do you mean invalid html structure?

Comment: You shouldn't add text between rows.

Comment: Hmmm, Could you post a snippet of the actual rendered tables so we see the HTML structure? It seems to me that you use one table to represent multiple different things and then alternate a 'parent' and multiple children. The reality being that both the parent and the children are children of the same table parent. *Are you using the table just to do layouting?* I would just use two different tables for different concepts and put the 'parent' row actually outside of the table. Then the problem just disappears because everything has one specific meaning instead of everything being table rows.

Comment: I will show you guys the output inside of my web app. i will update my post give me a sec

Comment: please see my update guys on the top.

Comment: We need the actual HTML code so we can see how the structure is nested. Not an image of you logging the HTML, not an image of the rendered HTML. The raw HTML text generated by your loops.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki that is just a log so I can determine what class where item correspond

Comment: @Shilly ok shilly i will update show you my html structure on my view

Comment: please view my new update thanks

Comment: Hey.. Can you please add it to a fiddle and share the link with us .So that it will be easy to solve your problem quickly. Because we understand the problem. So unless and untill we touch the code we cant solve it. So try to share the fiddle.

Comment: @biswajit-rout view my fiddle,

Comment: Please upload a workable fiddle. using Jsfiddle. If its possible for you.

Comment: Hi everyone i will update my new post so it will better understand. thank you.

Comment: Why dont add a class 'parent' or 'child' for the rows as you are the one who generates them? So it's very easy to know if you have a parent-row or a child one.

Comment: @Meziane looking forward, let's say i already add parent or a child? so how can i validate? if that is a parent or child. in my onClick function?

Comment: How can i determine if the  Item_menu has a class of parent or a child?

Comment: It's very easy to check if the row has the class'parent' or the class 'child' using the jQuery function hasClass like here:  if ($("#myId").hasClass("parent")) {
..
}

Comment: provide your table with the classes 'parent' and 'child' set accordingly to your rows and I will provide a working jquery snippet as an answer

Comment: ok i already add a class I set the parent as condimentParent and the child as editCondiments.

Comment: @Meziane take a look for the new update post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192042/discussion-between-meziane-and-devge).